# CakePHP: comments plugin help

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to implement the cakephp comments plugin found here: http://cakedc.com/downloads/view/cakephp_comments_plugin

I have a projects_controller which I want to add comments to.

Everything has gone fine whilst following the instruction I can add comments and they are saved in the comments table but they are not displaying on the project view.

I assumed it was because there was no association between project and comments so I have created a belongTo and a hasMany associations between them but still to no avail :(

```
<div id="post-comments">
    <?php $commentWidget->options(array('allowAnonymousComment' => false));?>
    <?php echo $commentWidget->display();?>
</div>
```

This displays the add comments inputs and it DOES save comments and all the neccessary foreign keys, etc but it just doesn't display them

Anyone know what's gone wrong?

Jonesy

Comment: When you say 'sitting in the root' you mean of the plugin yes? In `/app/plugins/comments/` not in your project root. Also are you looking up the stuff from the plugin? By using the `'plugin'=>'comments'`

Comment: ah they just looked a bit of out place. but yeah in the plugin. Well adding the $plugins = array('comments'); doesn't help. I don't think it's being used properly because I intentionally misspelled comments and it didn't throw an error. the guide doesn't mention setting up assiciations, do I not to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason I thought the comments plugin actually displayed the comments as well. turns out it doesn't so I just added them myself